# Font rendering issues with wkhtmltoimage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, font-face, wkhtmltoimage

I have a Rails app which uses wkhtmltoimage to render an image. The font used in the image is Lucida Grande, included via inline data-uris. On my local Mac everything works just fine, but on the remote server (Ubuntu 12.10) the font just looks weird. Both are using wkhtmltoimage 0.10.0 rc2.

The left one is generated on my Mac, the right one on the Ubuntu server.

[image: Mac] [image]

Any ideas whats going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I haven't found a solution for this problem. But today I was lucky enough to find a workaround! :)

After reading Thomas Fuchs' [Embedding Canvas and SVG charts in emails](http://mir.aculo.us/2013/04/30/embed-canvas-and-svg-charts-in-emails/) I went the radical way  and completely replaced **wkhtmltoimage** with **PhantomJS**. I also used his [gist](https://gist.github.com/madrobby/5489174) to install some dependencies. And here are the results:

**wkhtmltoimage** local & remote:

[image]
[image]

**PhantomJS** local & remote:

[image]
[image]

Though there are still small differences, PhantomJS does its job quite good! So I will use this for now, and close this question :)